# Lucene Search in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-search-lucene

Has the Lucene Search library been removed from the ZendFramework 2? because I can't find it [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

It has it's own repo here:
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSearch

---

I couldn't find it. I wonder if it is interoperable with the previous version of the library. I also noticed that it was present in 1.9, but I don't see 1.9 available for download.

There was work being done in the 2.0 branch here:
https://github.com/Maks3w/zf2/commit/9796a6ff1f4fe71048b4f083f7ec746f4442e7dd
This refers to Lucene changes:
http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/BC+Breaks

More work here:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/40/commits

Don't see it here:
http://modules.zendframework.com/

Comment: Documentation is still scarce.

Comment: Note that you can install it via Composer http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer

Comment: have you tried this out in any of your application? Is this working properly. Can you please provide some more info (documentation) on this if possible for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they have made it an optional component. It lives in its own repo now: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSearch

Comment: Just saw your comment, was updating my answer at the same time.